# Integral without using substitution method.

Tags: calculus, integration

How to solve this integral without using substitution method? As I'm curious that is there another method to solve integral? I did integration by parts.

$$\int \sqrt{4-x^2} dx=x\sqrt{4-x^2}+\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx$$
              $$=x\sqrt{4-x^2}-\int \frac{4-x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx+\int \frac{4}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx$$
    $$=x\sqrt{4-x^2}-\int \sqrt{4-x^2}dx+4\sin ^{-1}(\frac{x}{2})$$
    $$2\int\sqrt{4-x^2}dx=x\sqrt{4-x^2}+4\sin ^{-1}(\frac{x}{2})$$
    $$\int \sqrt{4-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{4-x^2}+2\sin ^{-1}(\frac{x}{2})$$

Is there any other method can solve integral other than substitution and this? I think Riemann Sum also can be used to solved. But people riemann sum is not considered a method of integration. I wonder why. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By knowing what integrals of $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ are, allowed ;)?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a description of what you've tried and where you're stuck.  In this case, why are you disallowing substitutions?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you had $\int_0^{2}\sqrt{4-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x = \pi$, since it is part of a circle with radius $2$. Otherwise you need to do some work to figure out the integral, where substitution is the easiest.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar, actually there is a very nice geometric solution, fleshing out your observation about the definite integral, that avoids substitution.  I would say more, but I think the OP needs to say more first.

Comment: Yeah! I see it now as well using a drawing! clever However I think I will let my answer be until OP says more.

Comment: Just curious. I wonder is there another method to solve it without substitution. I mentioned that your geometric solution, how it's done ? @BarryCipra

Comment: @user219126, if you edit your question to explain what you know about the problem and why you are asking for a solution that doesn't use substitution, it will likely be reopened.  (In my book, "just curious" is a perfectly good reason!)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar, if the problem gets reopened, I'll let you take first crack at it, since it was your observation that provided the key.

Comment: @BarryCipra I think it can be solved by Riemann sum.

Comment: @user219126, you should put your thoughts into the question itself.  There is still not enough there to assess your understanding of what goes into solving an integral.

Comment: @BarryCipra I've put my thoughts into the question. Is it okay?

Comment: @BarryCipra ....

Comment: @user219126, the question looks to me worth reopening.  I'm not sure what you have in mind for using Riemann sums to solve the integral, but on the other hand when I first read the question I couldn't imagine how (or why) you would solve the integral except by substitution.

Answer (score 6):

#### Method 1: Integration by parts

> $$ \int \sqrt{a^2-x^2\,} \,\mathrm{d}x
>  = \frac{x}{2}\sqrt{a^2-x^2\,} + \frac{a}{2} \int \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2\,}\,}\mathrm{d}x \tag{1} $$

Pick $v' = x$ and $u = \sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ then solve with respect to $\int \sqrt{a^2-x^2\,} \,\mathrm{d}x$. Next part is to remember the derivative of the inverse sine function.
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \arcsin x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2\,}\,} \tag{2}
$$

Hence by using the chain rule, you can show that

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \arcsin \left( \frac{x}{a} \right) = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2\,}\,} \tag{3}
$$

Integrating $(3)$ w.r.t $x$ and then inserting the result into $(1)$ completes the calculations. I will leave it to you to fill in the details. Just ask if any part were particularly confusing.

---

#### Method 2: Geometric considerations

here is a proof without words. I was able to discover this through the help of *Barry Cipra* in the comments above.

[image]

> $$ \int_0^x \sqrt{a^2-t^2\,} \,\mathrm{d}t
>  = \color{blue}{\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{a^2-x^2\,}} + \color{green}{\frac{a^2}{2} \arcsin \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)}  $$

Be warned, spoilers ahead.

> The total area of a circle is $\pi a^2$. The area of the sector can be obtained by multiplying the circle's area by the ratio of the angle and $2 \pi$ (because the area of the sector is proportional to the angle, and $2 \pi$ is the angle for the whole circle, in radians): $$ A = \pi a^2 \cdot \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} = \frac{a^2}{2} \theta $$ The rest follows since $\sin \theta = x/a$, where $a$ of course is the hypotenuse since it is the radius of the circle $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$. The area of the triangle should be straigt forward to figure out.

Comment: what happens if $x < 0?$

Comment: you would then mirror the figure, and the calculations would be identical =)

Comment: wont you get negative areas?

Comment: You are still above the x-axis. You would get $\int_0^{-x} \sqrt{a^2-t^2\,} \,\mathrm{d}t
 = \color{blue}{\frac{-x}{2}\sqrt{a^2-(-x)^2\,}} + \color{green}{\frac{a^2}{2} \arcsin \left(\frac{-x}{a}\right)}$
Because $x$ is now negative.. Is this suprising to you?

Comment: if $x < 0, $ then you will need $\pi + \sin^{-1}(x)$ for the angle of the sector. it includes the quarter of a circle in addition to the triangle. you will have to argue much more carefully. but you can avoid all this if you keep $x \ge 0$ and deal with $x < 0$ by some sort of symmetry.

Comment: @abel, the point is to get a function whose derivative is $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$.  For that purpose, it suffices to assume $x\gt0$.  The only thing you have to check is that the answer has the same domain as the integrand (which is why the indefinite integral of $1/x$ is properly $\ln|x|$, not just $\ln x$).

Comment: @BarryCipra, i upvoted the answer. i appreciate the geometric argument; i guess i was nitpicking.

Comment: @abel, I always appreciate a good nitpick ;-)